# series of 2D arrays with different dimension lengths in feed_dict

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

I have a series of 2d arrays which always differ for one dimension size, e.g. (20,87), (20,100), (20,76), etc... Those arrays are composed by Mel-frequency cepstrum coefficients (mfccs) for time steps (times), so (mfccs, times).

In oder to train a CNN in Tensorflow, I need to feed a dictionary with a batch of some of those 2d arrays.

I would like to have a 3d array because my input tensor would be: x=tf.placeholder('float', shape=(n,mfccs, times)), where n is the batch size. So the batch would be a 3d array with this shape: (n,mfccs,times), where only the size of times dimension changes.

I thought also to use a list of 2d arrays instead of a 3d array. But is it possible to feed a list in the feed_dict (e.g. feed_dict={ x: list?})? if yes, how do you do that?

Many thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: use a list of numpy arrays? It's hard to say any more than that without some additional context....

Comment: Add them all to a list !!

Comment: So actually I did create a list of arrays, but since I have to feed them in a dictionary in Tensorflow, I am not sure whether I can use a list. And if I can , how would you feed this list of 2d arrays?

Comment: You can use `+` operator or `__iadd__` special method.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: The usual solution would be to pad each of the batch elements to the length of the longest list, then use a standard dense Tensor. For most cases this is going to be most efficient. It would also be *possible* to feed these in and then construct a SparseTensor with them, but convolution operations are not going to be happy working on SparseTensors, so I wouldn't recommend it here. For more advanced batching of ragged sequences, there is `SequenceQueueingStateSaver`, which essentially plays Tetris with your examples. I'd need more details about the model to know which of these to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

For different sizes, but acting as an array, one can try list:

```
a = [[0]*87 for range(20)]
b = [[0]*100 for range(20)]
c = [[0]*76 for range(20)]

big_list = []
big_list.append(a)
big_list.append(b)
big_list.append(c)
```

After all this, `big_list` has length of 3, where each elements contains respective list/array.

Comment: Why do you use the `*` operator for one dimmension and not for the other?

Comment: I should have given more details about the problem, sorry. Those 2d arrays are input data to a CNN in Tensorflow. I thought to have a big list, but can I feed this list in feed_dict={ x: big_list? } ? if yes, how do you do that?

Comment: @EmanuelaLiaci I think you should edit your question to include what you're trying to do with tensorflow.